# How automatically adjust div's width using CSS?

Tags: css, html, width

Consider the [following example](http://jsfiddle.net/eRDRA/17/):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">Some text here</div><div class="right">Hello Stack Overflow</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
}
.left {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
}
.right {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

I would like to force the width of the green `div` to be as big as possible, according to the width of the red one. The width of the red `div` can vary according to `div`'s content. So, for example, if the width of the red `div` is 150px, the width of the green one should be 250px. This should always be true:

```
green div width + red div width = 400px
```

How could I achieve this using CSS ?

No Javascript please...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As sandeep said earlier, but [force the green div to take up as much space as possible](http://jsfiddle.net/eRDRA/18/).

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    display:table;
}
.left {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
.right {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Note that divs-as-tables is not supported by IE7 and below.

Answer (score 1):

make be that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/eGphW/

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    display:table;
}
.left {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: table-cell;
}
.right {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

you can use div as a table.

Comment: Not exactly. In your example the red div has an extra space on its right. The width of the right div should be as small as possible (and the width of the green div should be the rest).